# Issue when creating AWS fargate task definition json

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to create a json file (task definiton for AWS fargate) using jq from my gitlab pipeline.

I want to achieve this configuration building a block with "logConfiguration" and "logDriver", see right below:

```
"logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "awslogs-wordpress",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-example"
                }
            },
```

1) I have my initial json file below, where I introduce some values with commands on point #2:

```
{
  "family": "",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "image": ":",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3091,
          "hostPort": 3091,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "cpu": "256",
  "memory": "512"
}
```

2) When I do these commands with jq on my gitlab pipeline I achieve part of what I want, it seems fine, and I get the json on point #2.A but **I realized it output 3 times "LogDriver"** which is not right:

```
jq '.containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.options."awslogs-group"="'my_grup'"' tmp_task > ejm.json &&
jq '.containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.options."awslogs-region"="'eu-west-2'"' ejm.json > tmp_task &&
jq '.containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.options."awslogs-stream-prefix"="'ecsx'"' tmp_task > ejm.json
```

2.A)

```
{
  "family": "my_branch",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::235907124541:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "image": ":",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3091,
          "hostPort": 3091,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "my_grup",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecsx"
        },
        "logDriver": "awslogs"
      },
      "logDriver": "awslogs"
    },
    {
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs"
      }
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "cpu": "256",
  "memory": "512"
}
```

As you can see on point #2.A above, the config "logDriver" is written few times, and when the task definition is created within AWS fargate no logs are available in CloudWatch, because it is not picking the "logDriver" configuration, yes there is a log group in CloudWatch, but neither stdout nor stderr is captured from the container because "logDriver" is not being correctly introduced in the json task.

THE RIGHT JSON TASK DEFINITION SHOULD BE AS THE ONE IN THE LINK BELOW.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/using_awslogs.html

Potential solution is to understand how to correctly write into the json file, or if someone has a better idea of how to put this json task in a pipeline.

Looking forward to get some ideas from you, and thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Is this an aws question or a jq one?

Comment: @oguzismail It could be both, because if I am taking the wrong approach to create this json task with jq, someone experience on AWS can advise something more convenient to accomplish this. Does it make sense?, cheers.

Comment: But if someone goes out of their way and posts an answer completely based on jq before that, it would be a waste of time for them

Comment: @oguzismail Agree with your point. Removed the AWS tags, so it will be taken as a jq question, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the task with just one invocation of jq, and without using the shell's support for string interpolation, which is error-prone.  For example:

```
jq --arg group my_grup --arg region eu-west-2 --arg prefix ecsx '
  .containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.options
    = {"awslogs-group": $group,
       "awslog-region": $region,
       "awslogs-stream-prefix": $prefix}' input.json
```

You can add .logDriver similarly (in the one invocation of jq).

Comment: One thing from a beginner with jq, I got some errors when executing your example as below, I cannot figure out how to introduce the .logDriver, Would it be possible to for you to check this? 
$ jq --arg group my_grup --arg region eu-west-2 --arg prefix ecsx '
→   containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.options
→     = {"awslogs-group": $group,
→        "awslog-region": $region,
→        "awslogs-stream-prefix": $prefix}' ejm.json
jq: error: containerDefinitions/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 2:
  containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.options
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Sorry, a `.` went missing. Fixed.